# How to prove MLE of variance is biased

Tags: statistics

How to show the

$$
E(\Sigma_{MLE})=E\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}({x}_{i}-{\mu}_{MLE})({x}_{i}-\mathbf{{\mathbf{\mu}}}_{MLE})'\right)=\dfrac{n-1}{n}\Sigma
$$

Where ${\mu}_{MLE}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_{i}$
  and ${x}_{i}\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$
  and $i=1,\ldots,n$

Here is what I've tried:

$$
E(\Sigma_{MLE})=E\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}({x}_{i}-{\mu}_{MLE})({x}_{i}-\mathbf{{\mathbf{\mu}}}_{MLE})'\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}E\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}x_{i}'-x_{i}\mu_{MLE}'-\mu_{MLE}x_{i}'-\mu_{MLE}\mu_{MLE}')\right\}
$$

$$
=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(x_{i}x_{i}'-2x_{i}'\mu_{MLE}-\mu_{MLE}\mu_{MLE}')
$$

$$
=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \{E(x_{i}x_{i}')-2E(x_{i}'\mu_{MLE})-E(\mu_{MLE}\mu_{MLE}')\}  
$$

I think $E(x_{i}x_{i}')=\mu\mu'$
  but don't know what is the $E(x_{i}'\mu_{MLE})$
  and $E(\mu_{MLE}\mu_{MLE}')$

Comment: Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: Updated the question to include what I've tried in response to comment

Comment: Notice that you need to bring in the True Mean $\mu$ somehow before you get to the final proof. Hint for this: Add and subtract $\mu$ before you expand the initial $(x_{n}-\mu_{ML})^{2}$ into separate terms. Then also here, $x=x_{n}^{\prime}$ since the Random Variable $X$ takes on only real values.

Comment: Hint 2: Also you'd have to use the following fact somewhere down the line: $Var(\mu_{ML})=\frac{\Sigma^{2}}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}}
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)(x_n-\mu)'}_{(0)} = \sum_{n=1}^N ((x_n-\mu_{ML})+(\mu_{ML}-\mu))((x_n-\mu_{ML})+(\mu_{ML}-\mu))' \\[12pt]
& = \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu_{ML})(x_n-\mu_{ML})'}_{(1)} + \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu_{ML})(\mu_{ML}-\mu)}_{(2)} + \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N (\mu_{ML}-\mu)(x_n-\mu_{ML})'}_{(3)} \\[10pt]
& {}\qquad{}+ \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N (\mu_{ML}-\mu)(\mu_{ML}-\mu)'}_{(4)}.
\end{align}
The expression $(0)$ has expected value $N\Sigma$ since each term has expected value $\Sigma$.  The expression $(1)$ is something whose expectation you need to find.  Each of $(2)$ and $(3)$ is $0$, since $\mu-\mu_{ML}$ is a factor that does not change as $n$ goes from $1$ to $N$ and the sum of the terms $x_n-\mu_{LM}$ is $0$.

So now think about the expected value of $(4)$.  Notice that $(4)$ is a sum of $N$ terms that are all the same, so just find the expected value of one of them and multiply by $N$.